# SQL: Select minimum date difference for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Any hints to get the minimum difference between start time and end time per guid with the following data in Microsoft SQL 2014:

```
id| start time       | guid | end time
1 | 2015-04-05 12:00 | a    | 2015-04-05 12:30
2 | 2015-04-05 12:10 | a    | 2015-04-05 12:15
3 | 2015-04-05 12:20 | a    | 2015-04-05 12:30
4 | 2015-04-05 12:30 | b    | 2015-04-05 12:35
5 | 2015-04-05 12:40 | b    | 2015-04-05 12:55
6 | 2015-04-05 12:50 | c    | 2015-04-05 12:55
7 | 2015-04-05 13:00 | c    | 2015-04-05 13:25
```

the output I am looking for is:

```
id | start time      | guid | end time
2 | 2015-04-05 12:10 | a    | 2015-04-05 12:15
4 | 2015-04-05 12:30 | b    | 2015-04-05 12:35
6 | 2015-04-05 12:50 | c    | 2015-04-05 12:55
```

I have tried grouping by guid and using the DateDiff function, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

try with below query

```
;with CTE as(
    select id, sttime,guid,endtime
    row_number() over (partition by guid order by datediff(ss,endtime,sttime))
     from tablename
    ) select * from CTE where rowid =1
```

Comment: just a suggestion, write a line explaining solution instead of 'try with ...' sentence.

Comment: This gives the records with maximum date difference.

Answer (score 2):

This answer looks a bit like Indra's answer, however there is a significant  difference. Not using datediff, which will fail if any dates are more than approximate 168 years(or 2147483647 seconds) apart. Also fixed some issues.

```
;WITH CTE as
(
SELECT
  id, start_time, guid, end_time,
  row_number() over (partition by guid order by end_time - start_time) rn
FROM
  table
)
SELECT 
  id, start_time, guid, end_time
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: didnt know about 168 years limitation. could you please explain?

Comment: datediff returns an integer, meaning SELECT datediff(second, 0'1900' '1968-01-20 03:14:07.000') will work well returning 2147483647 however SELECT datediff(second, 1900', '1968-01-20 03:14:08.000') will fail since the maximum value for an integer has been exceeded

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GUID ORDER BY DATEDIFF(SS,STARTTIME,ENDTIME) ASC) AS RN
FROM YOURTABLE
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXIST` to return a row if no other row with same guid has less datediff:

```
select id, start_time, guid, end_time
from tablename t1
where not exists
    (select 1 from tablename t2
     where t2.guid = t1.guid
      and datediff(t2.end_time - t2.start_time) < datediff(t1.end_time - t1.start_time))
```

Note, I don't know SQL Server, so you'll have to adjust the `datediff` code above.